# How to use PCA with data of values with same units

Tags: pca, normalize, standardized, covariance-matrix

My data consists of 400000 samples with 3200 values of **same units** (400000x3200). I know, when the data has values of **different** size, first you have to standardize or normalize the data, so the scale of each value is the same.

But how to calculate PCA of data, which has values of the same units?
Is it necessary to normalize, standardize, center the data before? What about the cov-matrix for values with same units?

I hope somebody can help. Thanks

Comment: The data needs to be in the same scale. 
Which language do you use?

Comment: I'm using python. What exactly do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know a specific function in Python ( I know it in R)